# How to Convert Matrix to Bitmap/Drawable?

Tags: android

How do you convert `Matrix` to `Bitmap`/`Drawable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I do not understand your question. But if you want to resize a image then this might be helpful for you:

```
 Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Your image path"));
int oldHeight= ..
int newHeight = ..
int oldWidth = ..
int newWidth = ..
scaleheight= newHeight/oldHeight
scaleWidth = newWidth/oldWidth
 Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
 matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // recreate the new Bitmap and set it back
    Bitmap resizedBatteryImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmap, 0, 0,oldWidth, oldHeight, matrix, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
                Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
                Matrix mat = new Matrix();
                Bitmap bMapimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

the result of bMapimage have your bitmap image. And one more thing ,remember about the memory management while using bitmap,bitmapfactory...After using this try to set it as null.